Cabin in the Woods like movie (as in initial setup) from 90s with a ghost
I heard about this horror movie from a friend, he watched it around 20 years ago so doesn't remember much except it was great. It was probably trash (I don't trust his taste) but it intrigued me anyway because it is basically the same setup from Cabin in the Woods. Maybe it is too common a setup or maybe there are more similarities and I want to find out.
Movie info:
Not much info from my friend here because language barrier. But I can tell that it is American (or British origin), shouldn't be super low budget. He says, he saw it around 1999 but the movie could be older since home video. Most likely from 90s.
Details:
3 girls and 3 boys.
Cabin or house in the woods.
Cellar door. Cellar door banging shot.
Bridge collapsed or perhaps blocked by a tree when some decides to escape.
Villain is a ghost. Best clue, I think. I searched but google didn't help.
Does anyone know the movie?

Pretty much the plot of Evil Dead or its sequel Evil Dead II, though there were 5 people there, not 6. Do you (or your friend) remember the actors or what they looked like?

It is not Evil Dead, or so he says because according to him the movie was serious. I don't trust his sense of humor either but first thing I did was showing Evil Dead.

Allowing for a couple of minor alterations due to (possibly) faulty memory, this could be the original Evil Dead (1981):

There are only 5 people, not 6 (3 girls and 2 boys.)
The villain is technically a demon (or multiple demons) although they don't have physical bodies of their own.  They possess people (and trees) to do things which could easily be mis-remembered as "a ghost."

Details that match:

The characters travel to an isolated cabin in the woods.
The cabin has a cellar, which is used to trap one of the first people to get possessed.  The cellar door is frequently seen banging against the chains used to keep it closed.  Also the demon-possessed person peeking out from underneath and calling to the others.
At one point the Hero (Ashley "Ash" Williams) tries to drive the first possessed friend into town seeking medical help for her violent "condition," but he finds the only bridge has been destroyed.

The movie is very low budget, especially by modern standards, and the writing is quite cheesy.  Bruce Campbell built a career of campy 80s movies with this as his debut.  That said, it's also a classic horror film for the ages.  If you want to consider yourself "well educated" in the horror genre, you owe it to yourself to watch this movie at least once.
